# How to mock dependecies in another class with Mockito

Tags: java, jpa, junit, mockito, junit5

I am trying to do a JUnit Test. When I do this I get a NullpointerException. Can I solve this problem using Mockito  and if so, how?

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    Class1 class1 = new Class1(100, "TE", "TEST");
    
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    
    //I'm mapping class1 to class3 using class2.map, the usecase here is irrelevant for the problem
    Mapped<Class3> result = class2.map(class1, Class3.class);
    
}
```

Class2 looks something like this:

```
public Class class2{
   @Inject
   private EntityMapper entityMapper; //entityMapper: null

   public Mapped<T> map(Class1 class1, Class<T> class3){
      return this.entityMapper.map(class1, class3);
   }
}
```

When I'm trying to execute my JUnit test, I get a NullpointerException because the entityMapper inside Class class2 is null. So I want to mock the EntityMapper using the Mockito framework but I can't get around this Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your class2 is currently not properly unit testable. To make it testable, you need to use constructor/method injections so that we can mock and provide dependencies through test cases. See below,

```
public class Class2{
   
   private EntityMapper entityMapper;

   @Inject
   public Class2(EntityMapper mapper){
       entityMapper = mapper;
   }

   public Mapped<T> map(Class1 class1, Class<T> class3){
      return this.entityMapper.map(class1, class3);
   }
}
```

Then through your test case you can mock and set dependencies as below,

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    EntityMapper mapper = mock(EntityMapper.class);
    Class1 class1 = new Class1(100, "TE", "TEST");
    Class2 class2 = new Class2(mapper);
    
   //TODO: Configure result of mocked functions using mockito when-then methods.
   Mapped<Class3> result = class2.map(class1, Class3.class);
    
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer ;) Don't inject using type, use the constructor instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @nnhthuan :) unfortunately I can't use a constructor because there is none and I can't edit class2 because it was not implented by me. Is there another way? For example to mock the EntityMapper Depency using Mockito and weld?

Comment: That was very bad code. You should suggest changing the code if the code belongs to your organisation. If the code is from 3rd party, you can also write a wrapper class and then you can mock the wrapper class then. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating `Class2 class2 = new Class2();` in the `test()`, you can just use

```
@Mock
private Class2 class2;
```

at class level, and if it is a SpringBoot application you can try either `@MockBean` or `@Mock`